# Can not get this "Conditional Operator" program to work

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x,y;     
y = 999; 

int main()
{
    printf("\nEnter a whole number: ");
    scanf("%d ", &x);

    y = ((x >= 1) && (x <= 20)) ? x : y; 

    printf("%d ", y); 

    return 0; 
}
```

I can not get this program to do what I want.  I'm asking a user to enter a whole number.  If that number is between 1-20 I want it to spit that number back out.  If not I want it to spit out value for "y".  I do not want to use an "if" statement.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  It is not good to use a variable on both sides of an assignment.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: When the program runs it prints: "Enter a whole number: ".  When I enter the number the cursor just goes to the next line and blinks.  Nothing is produced.

Comment: What's wrong with the `if` statement? If you don't want to use the `if` statement, then C programming is going to be really frustrating. Use the `if` statement. That's what it's for.

Comment: I realize that.  I am new to programming and the workbook I have ask me to use conditional operators and NOT the IF statement.  I'm just trying to learn.  Can you explain why this isn't running the way I want it too?

Comment: `y = 999;` is an error since C99 (in C89 it is treated as `int y = 999;`), it would be better to change the code to `int x, y = 999;` or equivalent

Comment: @M.M. Is this allowed prior to C99? Given that y is already defined as int one line above. Assigning a value outside of a function (except an initializer) should throw some error on older C versions as well.

Comment: @Gerhardh in C you can have multiple definitions of a variable at file scope so long as at most one has an initializer

Comment: @M.M, ups, I forgot about this detail. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space in the scanf due to which you are facing an issue. Please remove the space and try running your code. Thank you :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x, y; 
y = 999;
int main()
{
printf("\nEnter a whole number: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
y = ((x >= 1) && (x <= 20)) ? x : y;
printf("The value is %d ", y);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
scanf("%d ", &x);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &x);  // remove trailing whitespace
        ^^
```

Because, the input needs to be an *exact* match for the supplied *format string*.

Otherwise, to match the trailing newline (whitespace), you need to provide a whitespace explicitly *and* a terminating condition, too. (*example: press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then input any other non-whitespace and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again*).

Comment: pressing Enter twice will still not terminate input -- whitespace in format string means *match any amount of whitespace*, so input continues until non-whitespace is received

Answer (score 0):

I executed the above code and I was getting the below error:
/temp/file.cpp:4:1: error: ‘y’ does not name a type
 y=999;
 ^
Compilation Failed

The below change addressed the issue:
int x, y=999;

Comment: This should be a comment